# Which is stronger, Super Saiyan God or Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragonball-super

In *Dragonball Super* and the movies it followed, we see two new major forms of Super Saiyan: the Super Saiyan God, which has a red aura and is achieved via a power sharing ritual among saiyans, and the Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan, which has a blue aura and is a form that saiyans who have previously become Super Saiyan Gods can become, thanks to absorbing some of the godly power.

What isn't clear, however, is if the Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan is of comparable power to the Super Saiyan God form.  Which is more powerful and -- if possible to answer -- why?

[image: blue and red Saiyans]

Comment: What about Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan Saiyan God Super Saiyan Saiyan God Super Saiyan?

Comment: @Richard I don't know, but I'm almost certain that it's weaker than a super god super saiyan god super saiyan god god super. Just sayin'.

Comment: What if Super Saiyan God had [eaten his wheaties](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXgRaqEwiIQ) that morning?

Comment: @Richard Well then [I hope you're both wearing clean underwear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4uwh8gnTrc).

Comment: @Richard Sorry, baked beans are off.

Comment: +9000 Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!

Comment: It's evident in Dragon Ball Super that Goku, at least, considers Super Saiyan Blue (SSJB) to be stronger than Super Saiyan Red (SSJR) by the fact of the order of forms uses to escalate a fight. For example, take the fight with Jiren. At one point in the fight Goku attacks Jiren in his base form, then SSJ2, then SSJR, then SSJB. With each transformation he's forcing Jiren to react more and more until SSJB kaio-ken at which point he seems to be roughly on Jiren's level.

Then there's the fact that Goku can kaio-ken in SSJB and not SSJR which gives it a huge edge.

Comment: See this clip from Dragon Ball Super: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG_Nkveg9xw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Dragonball Wikia](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_God_Super_Saiyan), Super Saiyan Blue is more powerful than Super Saiyan God. It's said to "far exceed it's predecessor". Though, apparently even in this form, Beerus is still unbeatable.

Here's a video that discusses it. It mentions the manga, which states that Blue is much stronger than Red. I believe this may better answer your question.

Comment: That Wiki is... dubious. Is there anything in the show, or perhaps word from Toriyama, to support it? Also, I don't get how it can far exceed its predecessor and still lose, since Beerus was at 70% against the SSG form.

Comment: @Axelrod: Would depend on definition of "far" I guess. Near as I can figure, in terms of power levels, far could be a 1000 point jump. I've found other articles which debate and say that Blue is more powerful, but I've seen a couple that say they are equal. I'm not sure Toriyama has stated it explicitly yet.

Comment: Do you read the manga? Maybe there's something there.

Comment: @Axelrod: I've found a video that I added to the answer, which covers a few more things. The video mentions that the manga states Blue is stronger, and that there's a mention in DB Super where Goku mentions that Blue is stronger as well.

Comment: You'll be getting the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Super Saiyan God has a multiplier of x2000. Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan is basically Super Saiyan multiplier + Super Saiyan God multiplier. Super Saiyan multiplier is x50, so 200 x 50 = 100,000. Super Saiyan Blue/Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan is 50 times stronger than Super Saiyan God.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Although this answer may be accurate, it would be a lot better if you edited it to add a canon source for all this information.

Answer (score 0):

Super Saiyan God - Red / Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan- Blue

This is my theory from **previous episode aired at 5th and 12th Nov 2017 , Episode no 114 and 115**(for reference), where Goku Fight Caulifa and Kale (later becomes Kefla through fusion)

In both those episodes it is shown (action speaks more than words) that blue is stronger and more efficient than red.

You will understand what I mean if you truly understand Goku's fighting style

Comment: Where is this information from?

Comment: As Mooz says, can you provide an answer for your claims?

Comment: Can you summarize the events of those episodes, and how they prove that SSGSS is stronger than SSG?